# I need to know how to automatically authenticate in Flickr

Tags: authentication, automation, oauth, flickr

Everything I have tried requires the end user to sign in to yahoo...this won't work because the end user doesn't know the password or the username. This should be automated otherwise flickr wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't get this to work the way you want.  OAuth requires the end user to authenticate with the service (Flickr) and physically authorize your application.  So at the very least, you're going to have to interact with their server as a user if you want to authorize your application for use.

As a side note, you may want to investigate whether or not you can POST the required variables to Yahoo via some sort of script.  Use Firefox and the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) extension to view the POST information.  This may or may not work, as my previous experience with some Yahoo forms require cookies designed to foil robotic submissions.